# Filter by Condition occurring Consecutively in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I'm hoping to see if there is a dplyr solution to this problem as I'm building a survival dataset.

I am looking to create my 'event' coding that would satisfy a particular condition if it occurs twice consecutively. In this case, the event condition would be if Var was > 21 for two consecutive dates. For example, in the following dataset:

```
ID     Date       Var
1      1/1/20     22
1      1/3/20     23
2      1/2/20     23
2      2/10/20    18
2      2/16/20    21
3      12/1/19    16
3      12/6/19    14
3      12/20/19   22
```

In this case, patient 1 should remain, and patient 2 and 3 should be filtered out because > 21 did not happen consecutively, and then i'd like to simply take the maximum date by each ID so that I can easily calculate the time to the event.

Final result:

```
    ID     Date       Var
    1      1/3/20     23
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the dates are sorted (latest date is later in the table) this should work. However, this is in data.table since I dont use dplyr that much, however it should be pretty similar.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df = df[Var > 21 & shift(Var > 21, n = -1), ]
df = unique(df, by = "ID", fromLast = T)
```

Comment: This works great. I actually just used shift my dpylr filter and it worked great. Thanks!